# Bash if else if conditions issue

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying some simple bash scripting, and I am working on a simple comparison script, where the program reads a character `char`, and if it is "Y" or "y", it prints "YES", and if it is "N" or "n", it is "NO". The letters Y, y, N, n are supposedly the only ones that will be used as input.

```
#!/bin/sh

read char
if (( $char = "Y" )) || (( $char = "y" ))
then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

The above script works with Y or y, but when I try to put N or n, it still prints "YES", and I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I know it's something to do with the parentheses, because when I use a syntax with brackets, like this

```
if [ "$char" == "Y" ] || [ "$char" == "y" ]
```

it works just fine.
I have tried all the combinations for the parentheses, like

```
if (( "$char" = "Y" )) || (( "$char" = "y" ))
```

or

```
if (( $char == "Y" )) || (( $char == "y" ))
```

or

```
if (( "$char" == "Y"))  ||  (("$char" == "y" ))
```

or

```
if (( "$char" == "Y"  ||  "$char" == "y" ))
```

but none of them work.
Can you please tell me what is the mistake I am making?

Comment: `sh` is not `bash`

Comment: You are right. Should I change it in the original post or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(( ... ))` is for arithmetic *only*; you are performing string comparison. Use `[[` instead. You can use pattern matching to check for either upper- or lowercase at the same time.

```
if [[ $char = [Yy] ]]; then
```

If you really want to use `/bin/sh` for portability, then use two `[` commands:

```
if [ "$char" = Y ] || [ "$char" = y ]; then
```